# Tab Bar Controller: executing code before switching view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar, uitabbaritem

I want to execute some code, before showing another view, when a user pushes the Bar Item with different view in a Tab Bar Controller.

I am trying to use delegation in my class:

`@interface HPAAddCarOverallInfoTableViewController () <UITabBarControllerDelegate>`

And I get close to my problem by using delegates method:

```
-(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

Unfortunately, `(UIViewController *)viewController` holds information about selected View Controller and not information about from what View Controller it was selected.

**Question:**
Can You tell me, please. How I can get information which will tell me from what displayed view the Tab Bar Item was pushed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement [`-tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:`](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITabBarControllerDelegate/tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:) in your tab bar controller delegate. You'll get that message before the new view controller is actually selected, so you can find out what view controller is *currently* selected, perhaps saving it in an ivar or something. Maybe you can do the work you need to do in that method, or maybe you'll wait until the `...didSelectViewController:` message, but either way you'll know both the old and new view controllers.

Comment: Thank You for Your reply! I have to know information about current Tab Bar. I guess, the best way as you mentioned - is to store information about previously selected Tab Bar. Because, as I can see, delegates methods can provide you only with information about selected Tab Bar and not with previously selected Tab Bar.